Using VBA to enter conditional formatting - condition formula cell refecence offset
    cells(5, 1).Select
    With Range(cells(10, 1), cells(21, 19))
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
                          Formula1:="=AND(" & cells(10, 11).Address(False, True) & "<>""""," & _
                                         "DATEDIF(" & cells(10, 11).Address(False, True) & ",TODAY(),""D"")<rngFLTDDays)"
'       .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).StopIfTrue = True
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior
            .Color = Range("fltDDays").Interior.Color
            .TintAndShade = Range("fltDDays").Interior.TintAndShade
            .PatternColorIndex = Range("fltDDays").Interior.PatternColorIndex
        End With
    End With

Code above is supposed to shade a table row if Today's date is within a certain time frame of the date in 11th column of each table row.  The WITH Range encompasses the entire table, excluding headers.
When this executes, instead of using Row 10 (first data row in table) as the formula base, the formula row reference is Row 5 (the position of the cursor).
Is there a way to define (in VBA macro) a conditional formula such that it uses the specified RANGE row as the base reference instead of the arbitrary position of the cursor?
PS: I tried this using R1C1 referencing.  Results were worse as I didn't know how to "lock" the column as I did using .ADDRESS(FALSE, TRUE), so it used a different reference cell for each column in the row as a comparison.
Thank you

The VBA you provided works for me (it highlights rows where the date value in column 11 is behind today's date by up to the date specified in rngFLTDDays. the formula returns #NUM if the date in col:11 is in the future.

The code for works for me too.  However, the filter formula in Excel is above is "=AND($J5<>"",DATEDIF($J5,TODAY(),"D")<rngFLTDDays)".  The 5 in the cell reference pulled from the SELECT which positioned the cursor at A5.
The range the formula is, however, is A10:Q21.  The formula should be "=AND($J10<>"",DATEDIF($J10,TODAY(),"D")<rngFLTDDays)".
I did update the code to force the cell position to A10 so the formula was correct.  I'm just asking if there's a way to enter a cond-format in VBA without having the manually position the cursor.  Kind of For My Info for future coding.
